# Why my head id is not displaying the next automatic id from the database in the swing form? How to code mandatory fields?

Tags: java, swing, validation

I have set the auto id generation to the form, it works properly. But, i want it like on opening of the form the ID should be displayed there on the frame, currently it displays zero every time i open the form.

May i know why it is not working? and What kind of code is required for setting mandatory fields in a registration form. "Like the details should not be saved, if the mandatory fields are empty. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import net.java.dev.designgridlayout.DesignGridLayout;
import java.sql.*;

class databaseprob {

    JFrame JF;
    Container C,C1;
    JDesktopPane JDP;
    JInternalFrame JIF5;
    JLabel i1l1,i1l2;
    JTextField i1t1;
    JRadioButton i1r1,i1r2,i1r3,i1r4;
    JButton i1b1,i1b2,i1b3;
    JInternalFrame JIF1;
    ButtonGroup i1bg;
    String i1type;
    int i1id;

    public databaseprob() {
        JF = new JFrame();
        JDP = new JDesktopPane();
        JF.setVisible(true);
        JF.pack();

        JIF1 = new JInternalFrame("Register",true,true, true, true);
        C = JF.getContentPane();
        C.add(JDP,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JIF1.setVisible(true);
        JIF1.setBounds(10, 10, 600, 500); 
        C1 = JIF1.getContentPane();
        DesignGridLayout layout = new DesignGridLayout(C1);

        i1l1 = new JLabel("Head ID : ");
        i1l2 = new JLabel("Type : ");

        i1t1 = new JTextField(10);
        i1t1.setEnabled(false);
        i1t1.setText(String.valueOf(i1id));

        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() { @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JRadioButton radioButton = (JRadioButton)e.getSource();
                i1type = radioButton.getText();
                System.out.println(i1type);
            }
        };

        i1bg = new ButtonGroup();

        i1r1 = new JRadioButton("Customer");
        i1r1.addActionListener(actionListener);
        i1bg.add(i1r1);

        i1r2 = new JRadioButton("Supplier");
        i1r2.addActionListener(actionListener);
        i1bg.add(i1r2);

        i1r3 = new JRadioButton("Staff");
        i1r3.addActionListener(actionListener);
        i1bg.add(i1r3);

        i1r4 = new JRadioButton("Others");
        i1r4.addActionListener(actionListener);
        i1bg.add(i1r4);

        i1b1 = new JButton("Save");
        i1b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                    Connection i1conn =  DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:TomsJava");
                    Statement i1stmt = i1conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                    ResultSet i1rs = i1stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM i1Register");           
                    int id=0;
                    while(i1rs.next()) {
                        id = i1rs.getInt("Head_ID");
                    }
                    System.out.println(id);
                    i1id = id+1;            

                    i1rs.moveToInsertRow();
                    i1rs.updateInt("Head_ID",i1id);
                    i1rs.updateString("Type",i1type);
                    i1rs.insertRow();   
                    i1stmt.close();
                    i1rs.close();           
                } catch(SQLException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                } catch(ClassNotFoundException z) {
                    System.out.println(z);
                } catch(NumberFormatException n) {
                    System.out.println(n);
                }

                JIF1.dispose();
            }
        });

        i1b2 = new JButton("Reset");
        i1b3 = new JButton("Close");

        layout.row().grid(i1l1).add(i1t1);
        layout.row().grid(i1l2).add(i1r1).add(i1r2).add(i1r3).add(i1r4);
        layout.emptyRow();
        layout.row().center().add(i1b1).add(i1b2).add(i1b3);

        JDP.add(JIF1);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new databaseprob();
    }
}
```

Comment: Additionally, you should adapt standard Java coding conventions with capitalized classes and uncryptic variable names to enhance code readability.

Comment: @Smutje - i will definitely try to implement those coding conventions from my next projects,  actually  this is my first java project, it has a lot internal frames, around 18 of them, so just for sake of identifying internal frame 1 components, i have added i1 infront of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why my head id is not displaying the next automatic id from the
>   database in the swing form?

This is because you update the text field just when you press save button. The code to get the last id and update the database record is all together within `actionPerformed` method here:

```
i1b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override // always use Override annotation
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        // all is done here
    }
};
```

You need to perform a database call to set the next id to `i1t1` text field prior to show the internal frame.

> How to code mandatory fields?

It depends on the case. One approach could be have a method that validates all mandatory fields are filled. For instance:

```
private boolean validateMandatoryFields() {
    return !i1t1.getText().isEmpty() && selectedOption != null;
}
```

Where `selectedOption` should be some variable or class member that holds the type selected on radio buttons groups. Then modify `i1b1` button's action listener to perform the update based on the result of this validation: if `true` perform the update otherwise show some warning to the user.

Note if you provide a default value to your components then you could get rid of validation. In this particular case if you make a radio button (lets say `i1r4`) selected by default then you wouldn't need any validation because `i1t1` will have the next id from the database as per my previous suggestion.

#### Off-topic

I know you're running out of time to deliver your project but next time you must consider perform database calls and Swing components updates using a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). This is because Swing components creation/update must be handled in the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) which is a single thread and time consuming tasks such as database calls or IO operations may block this thread, causing your GUI becomes unresponsive. You can read more about concurrency in Swing in this official document: [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you updating the text field, you are only updating a field containing a value you set before as the value of a field - I don't think Swing has a built-in model-view-binding framework for automatically synchronizing UI widgets and fields.

Solution: instead of

```
i1id = id+1;
```

write

```
i1id = id+1;
i1t1.setText(String.valueOf(i1id));
```

Comment: i tried that but, it does load the head id only after i click the save button, i want it like, it should be generated on opening of the register frame automatically.

Comment: Maybe you should have formulated your question different, because you want to perform the database operation before creating the frame instead of at button click.